# Given the 1- D diffusion equation $\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}-D\frac{\partial^2y}{\partial x}=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling, dispersive-pde

**Given the 1- D diffusion equation $\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}-D\frac{\partial^2y}{\partial x}=0$
, predict the evolution of an initia coastline described by
$y=500+A\sin(2\pi x/L)$, where $A=200 $ m and $L=1000$ m, assuming for $t>0$ that a wave field of height $H_{sb}=2$ m and $T=12$ s begins striking the shore at an angle a $\alpha_b=0.2$ rad. Boundary conditions are $y(0, t)=y(2\pi,t)=500$ m. Use any technique, analytic or numerical,
that you wish.**

I know that $D=KP_{sl}$ where $P_{sl}=1,752\rho g\frac{H_{sb}^3}{T}\sin(\alpha_b) $, but I have many doubts, for example the function $y=500+A\sin(2\pi x/L)$ should not also be in terms of $t$ and not just $x$? Could someone explain to me what to do or give me some help? Thank you very much

Comment: Initiale conditions deosn't depend on time!

Comment: @S.Maths 
What does that mean?

Comment: @S.Maths I would like to graph $\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}$ vs $t$  to do this I have thought to use that $\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}=D\frac{\partial^2y}{\partial x}$, but what time values ​​do I have to put? Why $\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}=D\frac{\partial^2y}{\partial x}$ does not depend on time?

Comment: I meant initial condition: $y(x,0)=500+A\sin(2\pi x/L)$.

Comment: @S.Maths 
So the problem is reduced to finding $\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}$ where there are the following conditions: $y(x,0)=500+A\sin(2\pi x/L), y(0,t)=y(2\pi,t)=500$?